# Word for "show interest more"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A college friend Pmed me today saying

"Can you meet?"

What I want to reply with is

"Nope"
"Show interest more to know the reason"

I just need a word for those 3 words here.
What I am trying to, as you can see,
I am not sure if he is asking this as a formality (because we talked a couple of weeks back and then yesterday I sent him something so maybe he just remembered that I exist and is saying so (sorry I am a overthinker! :P)). I am not feeling like meeting anybody this weekend because of lot of deeper reasons. I can tell him that but then again what is the point if he's  not interested?
So being like Sheldon Cooper just saying him No and giving him the option for the reason as well (so as to not be rude).

Comment: I'd suggest adding **"There are reasons"** without any further details to your "No". If he wants he can take that as an invite to inquire or just leave it at that. Not the single word you are looking for though.

Comment: That's Brilliant!

Comment: Glad if it helped! BTW for questions  about conveying a specific message you might consider https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t believe there is a single word to mean "show interest more". The statement  "show interest more" does not really make sense, perhaps you are trying to say "show more interest"  but given the context of the entire sentence even that sounds awkward.  If I understand what you are trying to say I would reword the entire sentence to something like this: " I would be interested to know the reason why you want to meet"   or simply, "Why do you want to meet?"  I am assuming that English is not your first language. As a multi-language speaker myself I understand how sometimes a simple phrase can be difficult to express easily.     
Also I would mention your use of "say" in your sentence "So being like Sheldon Cooper just saying him No...."    
This should be  "tell"   "..just telling him no..."   or "...just saying no.".
You can´t use  say followed by the object pronoun "him" unless you say, "  saying no TO him".
Some correct options are  "..telling him no..,   "..saying no..", or  "..saying no to him..".